# How finding smaller hash value validates a block

Tags: hash, blockchain

How generating a unique nonce and creating a hash value lesser than the target value validates a block(logic).I have searched so many articles still cant find a better answer for this .Can someone explain this.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? You have to try to find a hash which's value is less than the target value. For that, you have to change the nonce that you introduce in you block.

The info of the block doesn't change. You can only change the nonce. So, you try to find a nonce to get a correct hash value, .i.e a hash less than the target value.